# is it possible to make shared element transition from fragment to ViewPager inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I have Activity A that have a Fragment contains list of items and that item contains ImageView
when I click the Item I start Activity B that contains a ViewPager of fragments 
and inside each fragment there is  a ViewPager that contains Images 
what I want to do is to make shared element transition between the first ImageView in the items list and the first image that shows in viewpager of Images 
[image: ActivityA]

[image: ActivityB]

Comment: I am also finding its answer. if you have found plz let me know :)

Comment: Hi, this might help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlmWd-45KtY

Answer (score -1):

Refer this

Shared Element Activity Transition
 https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

And

https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb#.iew5qq2op